# Flot axis labels position in canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, padding, flot

I am building a Rails 3.2.11 app with Flot 0.8.1.  I want to render my Flot charts in PDFs using Prawn.  (I will Ajax the image data to the server using the *.getCanvas* and *.toDataURL* methods.) My Flot charts render in the browser just fine, with axis labels on the canvas thanks to the **jquery.flot.canvas.js** plugin.

**The Problem**

I am making barcharts with wide bars.  I want my x-axis labels to be centered under the bars, not centered under the tick lines (where they look a little too far to the left).

Before I put my axes labels on the canvas (i.e., when using HTML labels with no jquery.flot.canvas.js plugin), I was styling them with SCSS like so,

```
.flot-x-axis {
  .tickLabel {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-left: 16px;     // Nudges x-axis labels to the right
  }
}
```

Now, by rendering the labels on the canvas the above SCSS does not move the x-axis labels to the right. Oddly, the **font-size:** styling **does** work, but the **padding-left:** has no effect (also tried margin-left:).  I can’t seem to find an appropriate selector to apply the padding.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

**Update**

I am using the *align: 'center'* option in my code, but it does not seem to have any effect (i.e., same as if *align: 'center'* omitted). Please see, [How to use Flot canvas plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722858/how-to-use-flot-canvas-plugin). FWIW, I am using time-based data.

It looks like I am having a similar problem to this, [Flot bar chart month alignment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837524/flot-bar-chart-month-alignment-issue)

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/peterbloom/RyRYA/). Note: Renders fine in FireFox, but not in Chrome.

Well, of course it works fine in my jsFiddle, but NOT in my code. Guess I need to sharpen up my eyes!

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Flot Canvas plugin only recognizes a subset of the things that you can do with CSS.  Generally it recognizes anything relating to text style; font family, size, style, spacing and color.  It doesn't recognize box-model rules like padding, margin, etc.

It sounds like what you really want is to use the bars `align: center` option.

Comment: `align: center` works up to a point. It aligns the bar relative to the grid line. I'd really like a way to align the label so it appears "between" the grid lines. To me it looks odd that the bar is centered on the grid line.

Comment: Same as you Rob. I made the grid disappear vertically with this property and it's a lot better !  `xaxis: { tickLength: 0 }`